# Activate new CloudFront auto compression with AWSSDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, compression, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk

Amazon just introduced a new auto compression feature for *Cloudfront*, it's possible to activate it with the *AWS* console for *Cloudfront*:

https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/new-gzip-compression-support-for-amazon-cloudfront/

I've updated the AWSSDK to 2.3.53 (published on december 15) but I don't see anything related to compression in `Amazon.CloudFront.Model.DefaultCacheBehavior`.

Am I missing something or the SDK is not updated yet to reflect this new feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't indicate what language you are using, but from the version number you must be using the old .NET release. [Amazon hasn't updated that yet](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/commits/aws-sdk-net-v2). It is, however, [in the more modern interface as of v.3.1.35.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/SDK.CHANGELOG.md#31350-2015-12-17-2220-utc).